# Elasticsearch aggregate over bucket result

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to aggregate or count the result in the bucket.
for example:

```
{
 ID: 1,
 customer_name: a,
 age: 21,
 other_field: x
},
{
 ID: 2,
 customer_name: a,
 age: 25,
 other_field: x
}
{
 ID: 3,
 customer_name: a,
 age: 32,
 other_field: x
}
{
 ID: 4,
 customer_name: b,
 age: 24,
 other_field: x
}
{
 ID: 5,
 customer_name: b,
 age: 33,
 other_field: x
}
{
 ID: 6,
 customer_name: b,
 age: 17,
 other_field: y
},
{
 ID: 7,
 customer_name: c,
 age: 34,
 other_field: x
},
{
 ID: 8,
 customer_name: c,
 age: 26,
 other_field: y
}
```

my query is:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": { "match": { "other_field": "x" }},
    }
  }
```

hit doc's ID are [1,2,3,4,5,7]

What I want to do is find out every customer's youngest hit docs

my aggregate query is

```
    "aggs": {
        "distinct_user": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "customer_name",
                "size": 100
            },
            "aggs": {
                "youngest": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "AGE"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
bucket: [
 {
  "key": "a",
  "doc_count": 3,
  "youngest": {
  "value": 21
   }
 },
 {
  "key": "b",
  "doc_count": 2,
  "youngest": {
  "value": 24
   }
 },
 {
  "key": "c",
  "doc_count": 1,
  "youngest": {
  "value": 34
   }
 }
]
```

than using range aggregate to calculate age distribution

21~30: 2
31~40: 1

Is there any way to aggregate over bucket result?
Or something work around?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by leveraging the [`bucket_selector`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) and [`stats_bucket`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-stats-bucket-aggregation.html) pipeline aggregations. You can add as many aggregations as age groups you need. I've just added the two relevant ones to showcase one solution:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "other_field": "x"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "customers_20_30": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_name",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "youngest": {
          "min": {
            "field": "age"
          }
        },
        "20-30": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "youngest": "youngest"
            },
            "script": "params.youngest >= 20 && params.youngest < 30"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "customers_20_30_count": {
      "stats_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "customers_20_30._count"
      }
    },
    "customers_30_40": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_name.keyword",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "youngest": {
          "min": {
            "field": "age"
          }
        },
        "30-40": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "youngest": "youngest"
            },
            "script": "params.youngest >= 30 && params.youngest < 40"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "customers_30_40_count": {
      "stats_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "customers_30_40._count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the results, you'll get this:

```
"customers_20_30_count" : {
  "count" : 2,                   <--- 2 buckets for 20-30
  "min" : 2.0,
  "max" : 3.0,
  "avg" : 2.5,
  "sum" : 5.0
},
"customers_30_40_count" : {
  "count" : 1,                   <--- 1 bucket for 30-40
  "min" : 1.0,
  "max" : 1.0,
  "avg" : 1.0,
  "sum" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: I've tried, look like the "script" could only process the result from aggregate result, for example, if matched record is bigger than aggregate size, it will lose data which match the query, document number is much more than aggregate size

Comment: Pipeline aggregations work on aggregations results. Aggregation results are computed from all documents matching the query. I'm not sure what "aggregate size" you're talking about. Have you actually tried this and noticed "missing" data?